# Haxe; Is this possible to transpile a code into Ruby?

Tags: ruby, haxe

I'm planning to write API client for *aaS system (SDK).
IMO Haxe is one of the best choice to handle this situation.

How can I transpile the code into Ruby one?
(Haxe doesn't seem to support it for Ruby.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Simple: Hire someone to write a compiler which takes haXe as input and produces Ruby as output.

Comment: Is there a "transpile to Ruby" for one of the languages that Haxe does transpile to?

Answer (score 4):

There is no official Ruby target for Haxe.

However I remember that someone once started one. You might want to contact this author about his progress on this target:
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/2394

If you need to use Ruby for a professional solution, you might consider contacting the Haxe Foundation for a support plan: https://haxe.org/foundation/support-plans.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach might be to compile your Haxe and embed HashLink or C++ within your Ruby.

https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/6/12/calling-c-cpp-from-ruby/

Talking between Ruby and C++ seems to often be implemented using FFI in a similar way to how hxcpp communicates with native c++ code.

http://old.haxe.org/doc/cpp/ffi

New approaches to mix Haxe hxcpp with c++ can be found within the SnowKit community and might give you ideas on how to connect hxcpp with Ruby.

https://snowkit.github.io/linc/

with more docs on haxe c++ also hosted by SnowKit community

https://github.com/snowkit/hxcpp-guide

It might be that you can embed other haxe targets within Ruby like Lua, but as already stated Haxe does not currently provide a Ruby target.

Using other targets with Ruby might be achieved via FFI or similar.

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-lua

https://github.com/halostatue/rubypython

...

But may depend on the versions Haxe targets, a HashLink ( typed c vm ) bridge might require the most minimal connection but there is very little docs on this target so it maybe hard to setup ffi to ruby.

Probably not relevant but also came accross Haxe -> Ruby

https://github.com/Peekmo/ruhax

Comment: That would work if you'd like to use Ruby as the main language, but the use case of Ruby C modules is limited, considering the reason you use Ruby is the productivity it provides through its syntax and the myriad of gems and frameworks.

I think what the OP wants to do is to leverage Ruby's eco-system while using Haxe. That's a valid use-case and it'd be awesome to use Rails from Haxe. I could even think of some smart macro layer that could make it even more awesome.